# How to add on the left and on the right order like 1 to 8

Tags: python, list, numbers

Hi I have small problem I dont know how to add oder like from 1 to number 8 on the right and on the left of this program.[Here is the list but How to add numbers on the left and on the righ. I did this with letters up and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVMH7.png)

Here is my code

```
sachy = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]]

poradi = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
poradi_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for prvek in poradi:
    print(prvek, end=" ")
print()
print()

for seznam in sachy:
    for prvek in seznam:
        print(prvek, end=" ")
    print(end="\n", )

print()

for prvek in poradi:
    print(prvek, end=" ")
```

I try to write another list of order from 1 to 8 into the seznam but will always multiple by 8 becaouse of sachy that are 8x8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pair the row indices with the row itself, also use `" ".join()` for shorted code

```
print(" ", " ".join(poradi), "\n")

for idx, seznam in zip(poradi_2, sachy):
    print(idx, " ".join(map(str, seznam)), idx)

print("\n ", " ".join(poradi), "\n\n")
```

```
  a b c d e f g h

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
2 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 2
3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 3
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
6 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 6
7 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 7
8 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 8

  a b c d e f g h
```

Comment: it would be possible to do it somehow with my code, we haven't learned these yet.

Comment: @BradleyKohr learn what ? you won't be learned each method that exists, you'll have to learn them by yourself